# EF Code First cascade delete and update?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.3

My entities are these:

```
public class Customer
{
    public Customer()
    {
        Invoices = new List<Invoice>();
        Payments = new List<Payment>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public IList<Payment> Payments { get; set; }
}

public class Payment
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public decimal CreditPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal DebitPrice { get; set; }
    public DateTime PaymentDate { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CustomerID")]
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

and this is my context:

```
public class AccountingContext : DbContext, IDisposable
{
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Payment> Payments { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Payment>()
                .HasRequired(s => s.Customer)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete();

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

i get this error in *WillCascadeOnDelete()*:

> Error 1   'System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.RequiredNavigationPropertyConfiguration' does not contain a definition for 'WillCascadeOnDelete' and no extension method 'WillCascadeOnDelete' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.RequiredNavigationPropertyConfiguration' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   D:\Work\C# Projects\Visual Studio 2010\Windows\WPF\New folder\Accounting Without EF Code First\Accounting - Copy\DAL.EF.CodeFirst\Entities\Context\AccountingContext.cs 22  22  DAL.EF.CodeFirst

i want to delete payments of the customer cascading (**Just if** customer getting deleted). how can i achieve this in EF code first?

also i want to use cascade update.
please help me in these issues.
thanx.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Description

You need to configure the modelBuilder in your context.

#### Sample

```
public class AccountingContext : DbContext, IDisposable
{
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Payment> Payments { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Payment>()
                .HasRequired(s => s.Customer)
                .WithMany()
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you dknaack, but it doesn't work because my entity is Payment (not payments) and when i use **Payment** it give me an error.

Comment: Thank you very much. this works correctly. but how can i use cascade update? can you help me in this issue?

Answer (score 0):

**On Model Creating Method you need to make changes as follows**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
            //Disabling Delete Cascade
            foreach (var foreignKey in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes().SelectMany(model=>model.GetForeignKeys()))
            {
                //Disabling Delete Cascade on Each Entities
                foreignKey.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.Restrict;
            }
}
```

Comment: They want cascaded delete on one specific relationship. This answer offers neither: *no* cascaded delete on *all* relationships. Are you sure you answered the right question?