# Entity Framework POCO - Possible to set Cascade?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, poco, cascade, cascading-deletes

I have your basic recursive categories that are linked between each other. When I try to delete a category that has children I get your usual error.

What I always did is made a functions to recursively delete all children but I wonder can I just somehow set **CASCADE ON DELETE** somehow to my POCO class that is using EF so I would not need implement my own deletion mechanics?

### Error

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the SAME TABLE REFERENCE
>   constraint "FK_dbo.Categories_dbo.Categories_RootCategoryId". The
>   conflict occurred in database "Website", table "dbo.Categories",
>   column 'RootCategoryId'.

### Model

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? RootCategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category RootCategory { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> ChildCategories { get; set; }
}
```

### What I have now

Currently I delete relation before deleting a category. But what if I want to delete all child-categories recursively? Only cascading them will accomplish that.

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    var category = _db.Categories.Single(x => x.Id == id);
    if (category.RootCategoryId == null)
    {
        category.ChildCategories.ToList().ForEach(x => x.RootCategoryId = null);
    }
    else
    {
        category.ChildCategories.ToList().ForEach(x => x.RootCategoryId = category.RootCategoryId);
    }
    _db.Categories.Remove(category);
    _db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Category");
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is feasible as nothing prevent a `Category` To have, somewhere down in the relationship, path a reference to itself, introducing cyclic cascading. I'm far from an expert in Model First but if this is possible in Code First, you need to specify the CascadeOnDelete in the ModelBuilder. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523291/ef-code-first-cascade-delete-and-update

Answer (score 1):

The way I would approach this issue would be to use the OnModelCreating Fluent api.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity()
        .HasMany(u => u.ProjectAuthorizations)
        .WithRequired(a => a.UserProfile)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

}
```