# Foreign key constraint issue?

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework, relational-database

I've made some changes to my EF code first database and when I try to update it I now get the following error:

**Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.SupportTicketMessages_dbo.SupportTickets_Ticket_Id' on table 'SupportTicketMessages' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.**

Here are my entities:

SupportTicket:

```
public class SupportTicket
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Text { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public TicketUrgency Urgency { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public TicketStatus Status { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public virtual UserProfile Owner { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

SupportTicketMessage:

```
public class SupportTicketMessage
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public virtual UserProfile Author { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Text { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public virtual SupportTicket Ticket { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int MessageNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

What's the issue here? I don't see what's wrong.

Comment: you have specified cascade delete...   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523291/ef-code-first-cascade-delete-and-update - similar question

Comment: @MilenPavlov
But I don't see what the issue is. And I've never specified cascade delete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is the required `UserProfile` in both entities.

You have three *required* one-to-many relationships between `UserProfile`, `SupportTicket` and  `SupportTicketMessage`:

1. one `UserProfile` - many `SupportTicket`s
2. one `UserProfile` - many `SupportTicketMessage`s
3. one `SupportTicket` - many `SupportTicketMessage`s

(Left side is the principal (that has the primary key of the relationship) and right side is the dependent (that has the foreign key of the relationship).)

For required one-to-many relationships EF adds a cascading delete to the database by default, i.e. if the entity on the left side above is deleted all dependent entities on the right side should be deleted automatically.

If you would delete a `UserProfile` now you will have two cascading delete paths to the `SupportTicketMessage` table, namely:

- `UserProfile` -> `SupportTicket` -> `SupportTicketMessage` (because of relationships 1 and 3)
- `UserProfile` -> `SupportTicketMessage` (because of relationship 2)

This is not allowed in SQL Server and the reason for the exception.

In order to fix the problem you must "break" the cascading delete paths for at least one of the relationships. You can do that by either making the relationship *optional* (that is: remove one of the `[Required]` attributes on the navigation properties) or by disabling cascading delete explicitly. I would choose the latter option because changing a relationship from *required* to *optional* is kind of changing a business rule. I'd disable cascading delete for relationships 1 and 2 because, maybe, deleting a `UserProfile` should not delete all `SupportTicket`s and `SupportTicketMessage`s but instead the tickets and messages should be assigned to some "anonymous" default user, so the ticket history doesn't get lost when a user wants to leave the system.

Cascading delete must be disabled with Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SupportTicket>()
    .HasRequired(s => s.Owner)
    .WithMany()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<SupportTicketMessage>()
    .HasRequired(s => s.Author)
    .WithMany()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

(If you have navigation collections in `UserProfile` refering to `SupportTicket`s and `SupportTicketMessage`s you must use the `WithMany` call with a lambda parameter, like `WithMany(u => u.SupportTickets)` and `WithMany(u => u.SupportTicketMessages)`.)

Comment: Wow what a quality answer! Thanks a lot I get it now - it works great!
I really appreciate the help.