# how to make a model to generate a foreign key constraint that has cascading update

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I am using asp.net wepAPi,  I have a foreign key column between employees and employeeLoan;

```
public class Employee
    {
        [Key,Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public String EmpID { get; set; }       
     }  

    
  

 public class EmployeeLoan
    {       [Required]
        [Display(Name="Employee")]
        public String EmpID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("EmpID")]
        public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }  
    }
```

how can I structure C# model in such a way that it will  generate a foreign key constraint  that has cascading update like this

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeLoans]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.EmployeeLoans_dbo.Employees_EmpID] FOREIGN KEY([EmpID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Employees] ([EmpID])
ON UPDATE CASCADE -- I want this portion to be added but with this model it s not added
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeLoans] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.EmployeeLoans_dbo.Employees_EmpID]
GO
```

Comment: Have you tried using [Entity Framework](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework)?

Comment: @TheUknown I believe entity framework does not have cascade update feature,

Comment: I believe [it is possible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523291/ef-code-first-cascade-delete-and-update) but i'm not too sure havent tried it. I would let the database handle the `on cascade update` feature and then use EF to import the tables

Comment: I definitely add it to the database and when I run the query on the sql server it work fine but on my application entity frame work always throw an exception

Can some please help me I have a deadline on this project

Comment: well ! what is the exception ?